# Finding identical buttons with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, findelement

I am trying to find a button on a website, however this button won't always be there and there are multiple buttons that are identical in everyway. The `xpath` of the buttons is :

`//*[@id="inspire"]/div[3]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[i]/div/div/div[2]/button/div`

Where i is the i'th button. To find the correct button however I have to check the text in the first element (`/div[1])` of the `'/div'` list before the '/button/ (where you can see '/div[2]'. This text is specific per button. And I have a specific string I'm looking for in these div[1]'s and I only need the button above which is this specific string.

(I have already checked the string is indeed on the page so  the button does exist everytime I get to this step. I just need to find the button that is underneath it.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Answer (score 1):

use xpath with text filter e.g

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="texthere"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elems =elem.find_elements_by_id("id" )`
Then use loop to seperate all elements that have same locator .